# Will peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error: ever pass an error if the CBCharacteristic's isNotifying is YES?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

Is there ever a case where `CBPeripheralDelegate`'s `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:` will pass back an error when the characteristic's `isNotifying` property is set to `YES`?

Obviously this makes sense in the context of when an explicit read request is sent, but if the peripheral's characteristic is notifying the central and that notification is successfully received by the central then it doesn't seem like an error is possible.

The documentation for the method doesn't add any details to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the possible [Core Bluetooth Attribute Errors](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CBATTError) most would not seem to apply.  The ones that I can see that are possible (if not likely) are -

> - CBATTErrorUnlikelyError
>
> The ATT request has encountered an unlikely error and therefore could not be completed.

which seems to be a sort of catch-all "something went wrong" and

> - CBATTErrorInsufficientResources
>
> Resources are insufficient to complete the ATT request.

At the very least you should check for a non-nil error and not process the update in that case.  I think you will probably get a disconnect in most cases where an error is reported to this method.

Comment: Thanks, good idea to check the error codes. Hmm if `isNotifying` is set then no explicit request was made. The `CBATTError` descriptions seem to imply that there was an issue handling the ATT request, which in this case there was no request. The `CBError`s also don't seem to fit in this context.

Comment: As per the documentation, the error descriptions come from the Bluetooth specification. I am assuming (and it is just an assumption) that the "request" is an "operation"  - The notify operation is an implicit request and there could be conditions inside Core Bluetooth where the update is received and an error occurs processing it - the logical thing to do is to inform the delegate via this method.  Without seeing Apple's code it is impossible to say one way or the other, but defensive programming says you should check for an error

Comment: Seems like if there was an error with the operation then it would just silently fail or internally retry the read. There's not much the CBPeripheral can do to handle the error since it never made an explicit request. But you make good points about the best you can do is program defensively as we don't know Apple's implementation. Thanks!